# Deleting ListView Item From SQLite and List OnClick

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am having trouble deleting a ListView item from the list and my SQLite database when I click on each individual item that is added to my list. When I click on each individual item, nothing happens to my list or my database. Here is what I have so far:

My Database Helper:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class ExerciseDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static final String TAG = "ExerciseDatabaseHelper";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "exercise_table";
private static final String COL1 = "ID";
private static final String COL2 = "exercise";

public ExerciseDatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String createTable = "Create Table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2 + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addData(String item)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item);
    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public void deleteRow(long id )
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   db.delete(TABLE_NAME,COL2 + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
   db.close();


}
public Cursor getData()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}
```

}

My Main Activity Method to delete the Item when clicked on.

```
    private void listViewItemLongClick() {
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mDatabaseHelper.deleteRow(id);
            populateListView();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `public boolean addData(String item)` ---> You are adding some strings in the database row.  While deleting  `deleteRow(long id )`-->  `String.valueOf(id)`  if the string matches with existing then it will be deleted.

Comment: post your database structure please..